# Forzar idioma para testear aplicaciones Android

Tags: java, android

Cambiar el idioma del dispositivo para testear si funciona correctamente la aplicación en diferentes idiomas, me encontrado con el siguiente código en Java

```
    String languageToLoad  = "en"; // your language
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Recordar de ponerlo delante del `setContentView` en OnCreate de la `Activity`

¿Que otros métodos utilizáis para testear las aplicaciones que hacéis en Android en soporte multi-idiomaa, si usar emulador?

Comment: No es muy elegante pero, usar un dispositivo fisico e ir cambiando el lenguaje en ajustes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un método muy útil que se suele usar directamente en el dispositivo es instalar [App Settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings), la cual te permite hacer uso de varias configuraciones para determinada aplicación, como cambiar el lenguaje predeterminado, su resolución, si se usa en pantalla completa, etc.

Realemente es una herramienta muy útil para realizar pruebas sin necesidad de alterar todo tu teléfono.